# Abrir unicamente emails recibidos hoy con python

Tags: python, date, outlook, read

tengo un código que descarga emails de outlook según el criterio de un "asunto" específico. Hasta ahora el código funciona bien, pero quiero que además descargue solo el que email que haya llegado hoy, porque con este código se descargan todos los emails que encuentre con dicho asunto. He intentado agregar un parámetro en el fetch de "datetime" pero da error ya que dice que no es un parámetro de uid.

A continuación agrego el código que tengo.

```
import imaplib
import email.header
import os


# Your IMAP Settings
host = 'imap.outlook.com'
user = 'test@outlook.com'
password = '12456789'

# Connect to the server
print('Connecting to ' + host)
mailBox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)

# Login to our account
mailBox.login(user, password)

boxList = mailBox.list()
# print(boxList)

mailBox.select()
searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Test")'

result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
ids = data[0]
# list of uids
id_list = ids.split()

i = len(id_list)
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = id_list[x]

    # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    result, email_data = mailBox.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    # I think I am fetching a bit too much here...

    raw_email = email_data[0][1]

    # converts byte literal to string removing b''
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # downloading attachments
    for part in email_message.walk():

        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join('/Users/File', fileName)
            if not os.path.isfile(filePath) :
                fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()



    subject = str(email_message).split("Subject: ", 1)[1].split("\nTo:", 1)[0]
    print('titled "{subject}" '.format(subject=subject, uid=latest_email_uid.decode('utf-8')))

mailBox.close()
mailBox.logout()
```

Si me pudieran ayudar a descargar unicamente los emails del día de hoy, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Debes usar el criterio: `SINCE` en tu cadena de búsqueda: `searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Test" SINCE 14-sep-2022)'`.  Para la lista de criterios que puedes usar te puedes referir a la [documentación (rfc3501)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4)

Comment: Para el formato de fecha a usar, puedes referirte a la [documentación (rfc2822)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14). Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Mauricio. Funciona perfectamente. Lo único es que me gustaría que esta fecha no fuer aun valor fijo, sino una variable que toma el valor de la fecha que corresponde a cada día.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea filtrar una serie de documentos de tipo `email` de tal manera que se obtengan únicamente aquellos correos recibidos en el día actual (día en que se realiza la consulta).

Para ello se realiza la siguiente consulta:

```py
searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Test")'
result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
```

Sin embargo, esta consulta devuelve todos los correos cuyo campo `SUBJECT` es igual a `Test` sin importar su fecha.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es usar un criterio de búsqueda adicional en la consulta. El criterio `SINCE` devuelve todos los correos recibidos desde la fecha declarada en dicho criterio.  (Ver [documentación](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4)).

Por ejemplo:

```py
searchQuery = '(SUBJECT "Test" SINCE 20-sep-2022)'
result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
```

Sin embargo, si deseamos obtener el valor de la fecha de forma dinámica (obtener la fecha del momento en que se realiza la consulta), debemos utilizar la librería [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

Por ejemplo:

```py
import time

current_time_gmt = time.strftime('%d %b %Y', time.gmtime())
subject = 'Test'

searchQuery = f'(SUBJECT {subject} SINCE {current_time_gmt})'

result, data = mailBox.uid('search', None, searchQuery)
```

Hemos utilizado los métodos [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) para darle el formato adecuado a la fecha y [`gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime) para obtener el valor de la fecha actual con zona horaria neutra (GMT).

El formato usado para la fecha es:

- `%d`: Día del mes como decimal: [01, 31]
- `%b`: Nombre abreviado del mes segun el valor locale del sistema.
- `%Y`: Año incluyendo centurias (4 dígitos)

Para construir la consulta he utilizado cadenas con formato o [`f-strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.